# Getting an object inside of list of list

Tags: c#, list, generics

I am writing a C# application and I have troble parsing an object that is inside of list of list.
Right now, I have something like,

```
List<List<MyObj>> list;
```

and I am just trying to get the list of MyObj. And, it looks like the outer list is generic.
How do I just get the inner list (List)?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: use code markup to let us see the code please

Answer (score 6):

If you just want a specific one of the inner `List<MyObj>` then use the indexer

```
List<MyObj> local = list[0];
```

If you want all of the inner lists viewed as a single `List<MyObj>` with the inner ones just being combined together then use SelectMany

```
List<MyObj> local = list.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

List inner = outerlist[indexOfListYouWant]

A list inside a list can be accessed just like any other object in that list.

Answer (score 1):

You need only iterate over the outer list like so:

```
foreach(List<MyObj> innerList in list)
{
    // do stuff to innerList
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which is the "inner **lists**" do you want?

```
 List<List<MyObj>> list;
 List<MyObj> MyObjList = list[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

To access one (here, the first) of the many inner lists:

```
List<MyObj> inner = list[0];
```

To turn this "jagged" 2-dimensional list into a single one-dimensional list:

```
List<MyObj> oneList = list.Aggregate(new List<MyObj>(), (inner, result) => result.Concat(inner)).ToList();
```